# The value returned by a h:selectOneMenu / f:selectItems is always null for a bean

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, selectonemenu

I'm still trying to program an app with jsf2, ejb3.1, cdi and glassfish.
I have a form which have a selectOneMenu

```
<h:form prependId="false">
...
<f:validateBean>
...
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bottleManagedBean.selectProducer}" id="selectproducerb"
                                             validatorMessage="#{messages.bottleaddinvalideproducer}"  immediate="true">
                                <f:converter binding="#{producerConverter}"/>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{bottleManagedBean.producerItems}" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
...
```

The of the selectItems component are well showned but when I submit the form the value of bottleManagedBean.selectProducer is always null.

My formbean

```
@Named("bottleManagedBean")
@RequestScoped
public class BottleManagedBean {
....

private List<Producer> producers;

    public List<Producer> getProducers() {
        if (producers == null) {
            setProducers(producerService.list(Producer.class));
        }
        return producers;
    }

    public void setProducers(List<Producer> producers) {
        this.producers = producers;
    }

    private Producer selectProducer;

    public Producer getSelectProducer() {
        return selectProducer;
    }

  private List<SelectItem> producerItems;

    public List<SelectItem> getProducerItems() {
        if (producerItems == null) {
            producerItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
            for (Producer current : getProducers()) {
                producerItems.add(new SelectItem(current.getId(), current.getName()));
            }
        }
        return producerItems;
    }

    public void setProducerItems(List<SelectItem> producerItems) {
        this.producerItems = producerItems;
    }
...
```

The converter

```
@Named("producerConverter")
public class ProducerConverter implements Converter {

    @Inject
    BusinessService<Producer> service;

    private static Logger trace = Logger.getLogger(ProducerConverter.class.getCanonicalName());

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String id) {
        try {
            return service.findByID(Producer.class, Integer.parseInt(id));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ConverterException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) {
        String asString = null;
        if (o != null) {
            asString = String.valueOf(o);
        }
        return asString;
    }
}
```

I tried to debug the app .When I submit the form , the application never goes to the setter.

I also tried to add a valuechangelistener and my app never called this method.

Finally, I tried to submit an integer (eg. the id of my bean) and the value is well filled when I submit.1

So,... what's wrong ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how you should use the valuechangelistener properly in jsf2

Add `<f:ajax listener="#{bottleManagedBean.selectProducer}" />` to your `<h:selectOneMenu`

Like this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bottleManagedBean.selectProducerValueChange}" id="selectproducerb"
                                         validatorMessage="#{messages.bottleaddinvalideproducer}">
                            <f:ajax listener="#{bottleManagedBean.selectProducerValueChange}" />
                            <f:converter binding="#{producerConverter}"/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{bottleManagedBean.producerItems}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
```

and implement the selectProducerValueChange in your bean...